# Method that will process a payment for the given price amount

Tags: c#, oop

Im creating a customer.cs class that needs to take in a given price and returns a simple true or false bool statement on whether the card number was ran successful or not. Im stuck on the if statement part. I feel like if price is greater then 0 then the card number must be ran but Im having troubles implementing the running of the card number.

**Heres what I have so far:**

```
public class Customer : User
    {
        //Fields
        private bool _cardNumber;       
        

        //Constructor
        public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, string password, string email, int phone, bool cardNumber) : base(firstName, lastName, password, email, phone)
        {
            _cardNumber = cardNumber;
            
            
        }

        //OVerride the ToString Method
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Card Number: {CardNumber}";
        }

        //Properties
        public bool CardNumber { get { return _cardNumber; } }
        
        

        //Method that will process a payment
        public bool ProcessPayment(decimal price)
        {
           if(price > 0)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: is this a pretend app (like as a college test or fun project) or do you really want to present the credit card to a real card processor

Comment: No this is a pretend app. (Extra practice work before finals). The method just needs to process a payment for the given price amount and return true or false

Comment: I would have a class called CardValidator that checks a) if the number is valid (you make up the rules) b) the card has enough balance to cover it, you could decrement the balance for each transaction

Comment: CardNumbr being a bool is pretty weird, I would expect a string

Answer (score -1):

You should try like this in the method if I understand you correctly

```
    //Method that will process a payment
    public bool ProcessPayment(decimal price)
    {
        if(price > 0)
        {
            //usually in the last line before closing brace of if loop
            _cardNumber = true;
        }
        else
            _cardNumber = false;
    }
```